# gfortran error :unrecognized option '-shared-intel'

Tags: compiling, mpi

I'm using a parallel fortran code that use MPI libraries (mpich or openmpi) and a "mpif90" compiler to run. When I try to compile the code, I encounter this comment:

```
mpif90 -O3 -mcmodel=medium -shared-intel -fbounds-check -frange-check -Wunderflow -ffpe-trap=invalid,zero,overflow -fstack-check -ftrapv -g -c -o energy_MPI_2D.o energy_MPI_2D.f

gfortran: error: unrecognized option '-shared-intel'
```

What should I do?

Comment: Are you actually trying to use the Intel Fortran compiler? if not, it seems like the wrapper flags are set incorrectly. If yes - then the wrapper seems to be choosing the wrong compiler.

Comment: I am just using gfortran and mpif90 compilers; if the wrapper flags are set incorrectly, how can I fix them?

Comment: First, I would try using `mpifort` instead of `mpif90`. If that doesn't work see [How do I override the flags specified by Open MPI's wrapper compilers?](https://www.open-mpi.org/faq/?category=mpi-apps#override-wrappers-after-v1.0)